# 15k articles need 301 redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have got a 17 years old website which has over 15,000 articles. I recently got more than 4000 articles from static HTML pages and more than 9000 articles from another CMS (www.ez.no) migrated into one/singe WordPress website hence the need of 301 redirects through .htaccess.

My developer has redirected all of them in the .htaccess file.

The following is working without any problem for static HTML URLs:

```
Redirect 301 /aai-mmn1.html 
http://www.example.com/perspectives/a-tale-of-two-killings
```

However the following is not working, as this one pertains to dynamic

```
Redirect 301 /content/view/full/8590 
http://www.example.com/articles/evidence-still-matters
```

How can I do the following?

```
Redirect 301
http://world.example.com/content/view/full/8590
http://usa.example.com/content/view/full/8590
http://asiapacific.example.com/content/view/full/8590
http://canada.example.com/content/view/full/8590
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/articles/evidence-still-matters
```

Comment: Its not clear what you need. I presume you don't want ALL of the dynamic URLs redirected to the same page `http://www.example.com/articles/evidence-still-matters`?

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I do want all the dynamic URLs (i.e. subdomains of example.com) specific to that article redirect to the new URL. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mod_rewrite` is available you could simply do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^content/view/full/8590 http://www.example.com/articles/evidence-still-matters [R=301,L]
```

That said, if you have to do this for more articles than just one I would probably take a different approach:

1 - when importing the data make sure that the old IDs are ported over, if you don't want to use them as IDs again you could add them to a column such as `old_id` or similar.

2 - write a PHP script that expects an old ID as parameter and issues a 301 redirect to the new URL by pulling the reuqired info from the DB.

3 - add an htaccess rule to force all old URLs to the PHP script:

```
RewriteRule ^content/view/full/([0-9]+) old_to_new_article_redirect.php?old_id=$1
```

Comment: Demo for the basic redirect here http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=b3c5142d-32bc-5810-b70c-8c1aa40319c3

Comment: Demo for the redirect to script rewriterule here http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=67e5ea8f-6362-5c14-81f2-dd92a3ab7460

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I am afraid I know nothing about programming. 

I just opened the .htaccess file and saw all of these several thousand redirects.

Can there be simple code which I can use? For example:

    Redirect 301 ^example.com/content/view/full/92371
    http://www.mediamonitors.net/aai-mmn1.html

(^) denoting all the subdomains (i.e. usa.example.com, world.example.com)

And then I will use Find and Replace and make the change to all the URLs manually.

Thank you.

Comment: So, I will have to add the following code to each and every line of the dynamic URL something like the following

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^content/view/full/(.*)$ 
    http://www.example.com/articles/evidence-still-matters

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^content/view/full/(.*)$ 
    http://www.example.com/articles/articles/there-are-judges-in-the-hague

There are several thousand

Comment: Will I have to add the following code to each and every line of the dynamic URL? For example:

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^content/view/full/(.*)$ 
    http://www.example.com/articles/evidence-still-matters

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^content/view/full/(.*)$ 
    http://www.example.com/articles/articles/there-are-judges-in-the-hague

Please, elaborate as there are several thousands and I don't want to mess up the .htacess file.